# Why isn't the Client template working MVC Kendo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

the code is the mark up the grid still displays as it did before client template was applied. it also has a ton of errors in the console. I thought i followed the documentation. I also need to add an action link to the first three columns to a details page for that count. Thank you in advance any hope will be greatly appreciated

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<cigaretteLogMVC.Models.CigaretteCountData>() // Specify the type of the grid
    .Name("Grid")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<cigaretteLogMVC.Models.CigaretteCountData>)ViewBag.counts)
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
          columns.Bound(c => c.createdDate);
          columns.Bound(c => c.countDate);
          columns.Bound(c => c.bookQty);
          columns.Bound(c => c.actualCount).ClientTemplate("# if (edited == true ){#" +
            "<span class='edited'>#:actualCount#</span>" +
            "# } #");
          columns.Bound(c => c.bookVsActualCount).ClientTemplate("# if (bookVsActualCount > @ViewBag.max || bookVsActualCount < @ViewBag.min ){#" +
            "<span class='OutOfBounds'>#:bookVsActualCount#</span>" +
            "# } #");
          columns.Bound(c => c.dailyDif);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Notes).ClientTemplate(
            "# if (Notes != null) { #" +
            "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-tick\"></span>" +
            "# } #"
          );
        })
)
```

these are the errors

> Uncaught Error: Invalid template:'#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['createdDate'] ? '' : ''
> ##:data.createdDate==null?'':data.createdDate##= data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['countDate'] ? '' : ''
> ##:data.countDate==null?'':data.countDate##= data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['bookQty'] ? '' : ''
> ##:data.bookQty==null?'':data.bookQty##= data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['actualCount'] ? '' : '' ## if (edited == true ){##:actualCount## } ##= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['bookVsActualCount'] ? '' : '' ## if (bookVsActualCount > @ViewBag.max
> || bookVsActualCount < @ViewBag.min ){##:bookVsActualCount## } ##= data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['dailyDif'] ? '' : ''
> ##:data.dailyDif==null?'':data.dailyDif##= data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['Notes'] ? '' : '' ## if (Notes != null) { ## } #' Generated code:'var
> $kendoOutput, $kendoHtmlEncode =
> kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){$kendoOutput='<tr
> data-uid="'+(data.uid)+'" role='row'><td class="'+( data &&
> data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['createdDate'] ? '
> k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'" role='gridcell'>'+( data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['createdDate'] ? '' : ''
> )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.createdDate==null?'':data.createdDate)+'<td
> class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['countDate'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'"
> role='gridcell'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['countDate'] ? '' : ''
> )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.countDate==null?'':data.countDate)+'<td class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['bookQty'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'"
> role='gridcell'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['bookQty'] ? '' : ''
> )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.bookQty==null?'':data.bookQty)+'<td
> class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['actualCount'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'"
> role='gridcell'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['actualCount'] ? '' : ''
> )+''; if (edited == true ){;$kendoOutput+='<span
> class='edited'>'+$kendoHtmlEncode(actualCount)+''; }
> ;$kendoOutput+='<td class="'+( data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['bookVsActualCount'] ? '
> k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'" role='gridcell'>'+( data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['bookVsActualCount'] ? '' : '' )+''; if (bookVsActualCount >
> @ViewBag.max || bookVsActualCount < @ViewBag.min
> ){;$kendoOutput+='<span
> class='OutOfBounds'>'+$kendoHtmlEncode(bookVsActualCount)+'';
> } ;$kendoOutput+='<td class="'+( data && data.dirty &&
> data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['dailyDif'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' :
> '' )+'" role='gridcell'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields
> && data.dirtyFields['dailyDif'] ? '' : ''
> )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.dailyDif==null?'':data.dailyDif)+'<td
> class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['Notes'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'"
> role='gridcell'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields &&
> data.dirtyFields['Notes'] ? '' : '' )+'';
> if (Notes != null) { ;$kendoOutput+=''; } ;$kendoOutput+='';}return
> $kendoOutput;'
> at Object.compile (kendo.all.js:198)
> at Object.proxy [as template] (jquery-3.3.1.js:10268)
> at init._tmpl (kendo.all.js:63753)
> at init._templates (kendo.all.js:63850)
> at new init (kendo.all.js:59343)
> at HTMLDivElement. (kendo.all.js:2448)
> at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:354)
> at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:189)
> at jQuery.fn.init.e.fn.(:58432/CigaretteGrid/anonymous function) [as kendoGrid]
> (http://localhost:58432/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js:26:4889)
> at HTMLDocument. (StoreGrid?storenum=0001432:40)

Comment: Probably should post the errors. And your ActionLink question should probably be a separate post.

Comment: the errors were not helpful and a page long. your correct on the ActionLink I was just hoping some one knew off hand

Comment: @Brian bit presumptuous to assume that the errors are not helpful.

Comment: errors have been added

Comment: Markup does not correspond with error. Kendo template syntax is finicky - best to build it up step by step.

Comment: @SteveGreene good suggestion however I removed all but the last one. the one turning the notes column in to a check mark. That got rid the errors but no effect on the  grid

Answer (score 0):

this is what I found that works

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) // Specify the type of the grid
        .Name("Grid")
        .CellAction(cell =>
        {
             if (cell.Column.Title.Equals("Created Date") || 
                    cell.Column.Title.Equals("Count Date"))
            {
                cell.HtmlAttributes["onclick"] = "goToCount('" + 
                cell.DataItem.ID + "','" + cell.DataItem.countDate + "')";
            }
            if (cell.Column.Title.Equals("Actual Count"))
            {
                if (cell.DataItem.edited)
                {
                    cell.HtmlAttributes["class"] = "edited";
                }
            }

            if (cell.Column.Title.Equals("Book vs Actual Qty"))
            {
                if(cell.DataItem.bookVsActualCount > Convert.ToInt32(Session["MaxAlert"]) || cell.DataItem.bookVsActualCount < Convert.ToInt32(Session["MinAlert"]))
                {
                    cell.HtmlAttributes["class"] = "OutOfBounds";
                }
            }
            if (cell.Column.Title.Equals("Notes"))
            {
                if (cell.DataItem.Notes != null && cell.DataItem.Notes != "")
                {
                    cell.HtmlAttributes["onclick"] = "showNotes('" + 
                                            cell.DataItem.Notes + "')";
                    cell.Text = " ";
                    cell.HtmlAttributes["class"] = "far fa-comment-alt";
                }
            }

        })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.createdDate).Title("Created Date");
            columns.Bound(c => c.countDate).Title("Count Date");
            columns.Bound(c => c.bookQty).Title("Book Qty");
            columns.Bound(c => c.actualCount).Title("Actual Count");
            columns.Bound(c => c.bookVsActualCount).Title("Book vs Actual Qty");
            columns.Bound(c => c.dailyDif).Title("Daily Difference Qty");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Notes).Title("Notes");

        })
     )
     <script>
      function goToCount(id, date) {        
       alert(id);
       //redirect here
     }

      function showNotes(notes) {
      alert(notes);
      //maybe launch a modal here 
     }
 </script>
```